# What causes inhibited conditional statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

There are three options that the user can input in this program. He can choose to `login`, `create an account`, or `restore an account` using his email.

```
if user_ == 1:
    loginf.main()
if user_ == 2:
    createnewaccount.main()
if user_ == 3:
    restoreaccount.main()
```

Each option calls a function from a different module. And then returns back to `main` when the user is done.

For example, my code in the `loginf` module:

```
def login_information():
    login = input("Enter your username: \n")
    password = input("Enter your password: \n")
    if os.path.isfile('accountinfo.txt'):     # Checking to see if accountinfo text file is created.
        pass                                  # If not, then called back to mainf module.
    else:
        print("You don't have an account on file.")
        import mainf
        mainf.main()

    chobi = open('accountinfo.txt')
    particular_text = chobi.read().strip().split()
    if login and password not in particular_text:
        login_error()
    else:
        print("You've logged into your account.")
        chobi.close()
        return_back_to_main()   
def main():
    while True:
        login_information()
```

I've used a similar set-up for my other two modules. 
 
However, this is my output:

```
C:\Users\raamis\PycharmProjects\TicTacToe\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/raamis/PycharmProjects/scratchProject/mainf.py
------------------------
LOGIN - 1
CREATE NEW ACCOUNT - 2
RESTORE ACCOUNT - 3
------------------------
Select an option 1-3: 
1
Enter your username: 
Luke
Enter your password: 
RoboCop123!
You've logged into your account.
------------------------
LOGIN - 1
CREATE NEW ACCOUNT - 2
RESTORE ACCOUNT - 3
------------------------
Select an option 1-3: 
1
Enter your username: 
Luke
Enter your password: 
RoboCop123!
You've logged into your account.
------------------------
LOGIN - 1
CREATE NEW ACCOUNT - 2
RESTORE ACCOUNT - 3
------------------------
Select an option 1-3: 
2
Enter your username:
```

The functions are appropriately called for the first 2 iterations. But then when an option is selected on the third iteration, the program still refers back to the `loginf` module.

I've also had to import locally to avoid circular imports.

Comment: You haven't shown us the code which declares the variable `user_`, or the loop which asks the user to choose from your menu. Your code needs to be a [mcve] for anyone to debug it.

Comment: I don't know what `return_back_to_main` is but it horrifically sounds a lot like you've invented `goto` again. You haven't returned, you've revisited it and could eventually hit a stack overflow

Comment: `loginf.main()` contains an infinite loop of `login_information()` (no termination for the `while True:`). I'm not sure whether that would cause the issues you described, but why not call `loginf.login_information()` instead of `.main()`?